# Filtering columns in pandas by length

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I have a column in a dataframe that contains IATA_Codes (Abbreviations) for Airports (such as: LAX, SFO, ...) However, if I analyze the column values a little more (column.unique()), it says that there are also 4 digit numbers in it.
How can I filter the column so that my Datafram will only consist of rows containing a real Airport code?

My idea was to filter the length (Airports Code Length is always 3, while the Number length is always 4) but I don't know how to implement this idea.

```
array(['LFT', 'HYS', 'ELP', 'DVL', 'ISP', 'BUR', 'DAB', 'DAY', 'GRK',
       'GJT', 'BMI', 'LBE', 'ASE', 'RKS', 'GUM', 'TVC', 'ALO', 'IMT',
...
       10170, 11577, 14709, 14711, 12255, 10165, 10918, 15401, 13970,
       15497, 12265, 14254, 10581, 12016, 11503, 13459, 14222, 14025,
       '10333', '14222', '14025', '13502', '15497', '12265'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `df.columns.str.len` to get the length, and pass that to the second indexer position of `df.loc`:

```
df = df.loc[:, df.columns.astype(str).str.len() == 3]
```

Comment: It says: IndexingError: Unalignable boolean Series provided as indexer (index of the boolean Series and of the indexed object do not match).

Comment: Could you provide a little more sample of the structure of your dataframe? I'm not sure why you'd be getting that error.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/usdot/flight-delays?select=flights.csv
I am particulary using "ORIGIN_AIRPORT" in this case

Comment: Will you please provide the result of `print(df.columns)`?

Comment: It now worked with this formula

flights = flights[flights["ORIGIN_AIRPORT"].astype(str).str.len() == 3]

Answer (score 0):

one another possibility is to use `lambda` expression :

```
df[df['IATA_Codes'].apply(lambda x : len(str(x))==3)]['IATA_Codes'].unique()
```